# What is the most efficient method of performing the FIZZBUZZ test in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there a more efficient method of obtaining a list of numbers from 1 to 49 with a column containing the words `FIZZ` when the number can be evenly divided by 3, `BUZZ` when the number can be evenly divided by 5, and `FIZZBUZZ` when the number can be evenly divided by *both* 3 and 5?

My attempts are (CAUTION, this will empty your procedure cache, so DON'T RUN ON a PRODUCTION BOX):

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
/*VARIANT1*/
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
    FROM sys.objects o
)
SELECT t.RowNum
    , CASE WHEN ((t.RowNum % 3) + (t.RowNum % 5)) = 0  THEN 'FIZZBUZZ' 
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN t.RowNum % 3 = 0 THEN 'FIZZ' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN t.RowNum % 5 = 0 THEN 'BUZZ' 
            ELSE '' 
            END 
        END 
    END
FROM t
WHERE t.RowNum < 50;
GO 100

/*VARIANT2*/
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Num INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);
INSERT INTO @t (Num)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
FROM sys.objects o;

SELECT t.Num
    , CASE WHEN ((t.Num % 3) + (t.Num % 5)) = 0  THEN 'FIZZBUZZ' 
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN t.Num % 3 = 0 THEN 'FIZZ' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN t.Num % 5 = 0 THEN 'BUZZ' 
            ELSE '' 
            END 
        END 
    END
FROM @t t
WHERE t.Num < 50;
GO 100

SELECT CASE WHEN dest.text LIKE '%/*VARIANT1*/%' THEN 'VARIANT1' ELSE 'VARIANT2' END
    , MAX(deqs.execution_count)
    , SUM(deqs.total_worker_time)
    , AvgWorkerTime = SUM(deqs.total_worker_time) / MAX(deqs.execution_count)
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) dest
WHERE (dest.text LIKE '%/*VARIANT1*/%'
    OR dest.text LIKE '%/*VARIANT2*/%')
    AND dest.text NOT LIKE '%/*NOT_ME!*/%'
GROUP BY CASE WHEN dest.text LIKE '%/*VARIANT1*/%' THEN 'VARIANT1' ELSE 'VARIANT2' END
ORDER BY CASE WHEN dest.text LIKE '%/*VARIANT1*/%' THEN 'VARIANT1' ELSE 'VARIANT2' END
/*NOT_ME!*/;
```

I've modified my attempts to run each set of statements 100 times each, then show the times recorded by SQL Server through `sys.dm_exec_query_stats`.

The results:

```
            Runs    total_time      average time
VARIANT1    100     42533           425
VARIANT2    100     138677          1386
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a T-SQL solution that writes the first million numbers to a temp table. It takes about 84 ms on my machine. The key bottlenecks are waiting on the [NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL](https://erikdarlingdata.com/2018/06/the-nesting_transaction_full-latch/) latch and `CXPACKET`, both of which I don't know how to address other than changing `MAXDOP`. I wanted a query plan that can take advantage of parallel nested loops and demand based parallelism, which is what I managed to get:

[image]

The code is a bit long. In short, I join together two derived tables of 246 rows and 271 rows for a total of 66666 rows. Those rows are joined to a 15 row derived table which takes advantage of the fact that the FIZZBUZZ pattern is repeated for every 15 rows. The final ten rows are added in with a `UNION ALL`.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t;

SELECT res.fizzbuzz INTO #t
FROM
(
VALUES
(0),
(15),
(30),
(45),
(60),
(75),
(90),
(105),
(120),
(135),
(150),
(165),
(180),
(195),
(210),
(225),
(240),
(255),
(270),
(285),
(300),
(315),
(330),
(345),
(360),
(375),
(390),
(405),
(420),
(435),
(450),
(465),
(480),
(495),
(510),
(525),
(540),
(555),
(570),
(585),
(600),
(615),
(630),
(645),
(660),
(675),
(690),
(705),
(720),
(735),
(750),
(765),
(780),
(795),
(810),
(825),
(840),
(855),
(870),
(885),
(900),
(915),
(930),
(945),
(960),
(975),
(990),
(1005),
(1020),
(1035),
(1050),
(1065),
(1080),
(1095),
(1110),
(1125),
(1140),
(1155),
(1170),
(1185),
(1200),
(1215),
(1230),
(1245),
(1260),
(1275),
(1290),
(1305),
(1320),
(1335),
(1350),
(1365),
(1380),
(1395),
(1410),
(1425),
(1440),
(1455),
(1470),
(1485),
(1500),
(1515),
(1530),
(1545),
(1560),
(1575),
(1590),
(1605),
(1620),
(1635),
(1650),
(1665),
(1680),
(1695),
(1710),
(1725),
(1740),
(1755),
(1770),
(1785),
(1800),
(1815),
(1830),
(1845),
(1860),
(1875),
(1890),
(1905),
(1920),
(1935),
(1950),
(1965),
(1980),
(1995),
(2010),
(2025),
(2040),
(2055),
(2070),
(2085),
(2100),
(2115),
(2130),
(2145),
(2160),
(2175),
(2190),
(2205),
(2220),
(2235),
(2250),
(2265),
(2280),
(2295),
(2310),
(2325),
(2340),
(2355),
(2370),
(2385),
(2400),
(2415),
(2430),
(2445),
(2460),
(2475),
(2490),
(2505),
(2520),
(2535),
(2550),
(2565),
(2580),
(2595),
(2610),
(2625),
(2640),
(2655),
(2670),
(2685),
(2700),
(2715),
(2730),
(2745),
(2760),
(2775),
(2790),
(2805),
(2820),
(2835),
(2850),
(2865),
(2880),
(2895),
(2910),
(2925),
(2940),
(2955),
(2970),
(2985),
(3000),
(3015),
(3030),
(3045),
(3060),
(3075),
(3090),
(3105),
(3120),
(3135),
(3150),
(3165),
(3180),
(3195),
(3210),
(3225),
(3240),
(3255),
(3270),
(3285),
(3300),
(3315),
(3330),
(3345),
(3360),
(3375),
(3390),
(3405),
(3420),
(3435),
(3450),
(3465),
(3480),
(3495),
(3510),
(3525),
(3540),
(3555),
(3570),
(3585),
(3600),
(3615),
(3630),
(3645),
(3660),
(3675)
) v246 (n)
CROSS JOIN 
(
VALUES
(0),
(15),
(30),
(45),
(60),
(75),
(90),
(105),
(120),
(135),
(150),
(165),
(180),
(195),
(210),
(225),
(240),
(255),
(270),
(285),
(300),
(315),
(330),
(345),
(360),
(375),
(390),
(405),
(420),
(435),
(450),
(465),
(480),
(495),
(510),
(525),
(540),
(555),
(570),
(585),
(600),
(615),
(630),
(645),
(660),
(675),
(690),
(705),
(720),
(735),
(750),
(765),
(780),
(795),
(810),
(825),
(840),
(855),
(870),
(885),
(900),
(915),
(930),
(945),
(960),
(975),
(990),
(1005),
(1020),
(1035),
(1050),
(1065),
(1080),
(1095),
(1110),
(1125),
(1140),
(1155),
(1170),
(1185),
(1200),
(1215),
(1230),
(1245),
(1260),
(1275),
(1290),
(1305),
(1320),
(1335),
(1350),
(1365),
(1380),
(1395),
(1410),
(1425),
(1440),
(1455),
(1470),
(1485),
(1500),
(1515),
(1530),
(1545),
(1560),
(1575),
(1590),
(1605),
(1620),
(1635),
(1650),
(1665),
(1680),
(1695),
(1710),
(1725),
(1740),
(1755),
(1770),
(1785),
(1800),
(1815),
(1830),
(1845),
(1860),
(1875),
(1890),
(1905),
(1920),
(1935),
(1950),
(1965),
(1980),
(1995),
(2010),
(2025),
(2040),
(2055),
(2070),
(2085),
(2100),
(2115),
(2130),
(2145),
(2160),
(2175),
(2190),
(2205),
(2220),
(2235),
(2250),
(2265),
(2280),
(2295),
(2310),
(2325),
(2340),
(2355),
(2370),
(2385),
(2400),
(2415),
(2430),
(2445),
(2460),
(2475),
(2490),
(2505),
(2520),
(2535),
(2550),
(2565),
(2580),
(2595),
(2610),
(2625),
(2640),
(2655),
(2670),
(2685),
(2700),
(2715),
(2730),
(2745),
(2760),
(2775),
(2790),
(2805),
(2820),
(2835),
(2850),
(2865),
(2880),
(2895),
(2910),
(2925),
(2940),
(2955),
(2970),
(2985),
(3000),
(3015),
(3030),
(3045),
(3060),
(3075),
(3090),
(3105),
(3120),
(3135),
(3150),
(3165),
(3180),
(3195),
(3210),
(3225),
(3240),
(3255),
(3270),
(3285),
(3300),
(3315),
(3330),
(3345),
(3360),
(3375),
(3390),
(3405),
(3420),
(3435),
(3450),
(3465),
(3480),
(3495),
(3510),
(3525),
(3540),
(3555),
(3570),
(3585),
(3600),
(3615),
(3630),
(3645),
(3660),
(3675),
(3690),
(3705),
(3720),
(3735),
(3750),
(3765),
(3780),
(3795),
(3810),
(3825),
(3840),
(3855),
(3870),
(3885),
(3900),
(3915),
(3930),
(3945),
(3960),
(3975),
(3990),
(4005),
(4020),
(4035),
(4050)
) v271 (n)
CROSS APPLY
(
VALUES
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 1 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 2 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('FIZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 4 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('BUZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('FIZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 7 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 8 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('FIZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('BUZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 11 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('FIZZ' AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 13 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST(v246.n * 271 + v271.n + 14 AS CHAR(8))),
(CAST('FIZZBUZZ' AS CHAR(8)))
) res (fizzbuzz)

UNION ALL

SELECT v.fizzbuzz
FROM (
VALUES 
('999991'),
('999992'),
('FIZZ'),
('999994'),
('BUZZ'),
('FIZZ'),
('999997'),
('999998'),
('FIZZ'),
('BUZZ')
) v (fizzbuzz)

OPTION (MAXDOP 6, NO_PERFORMANCE_SPOOL);
```

Comment: It's a bit of a cheat that the solution doesn't actually do any calculations, but then that wasn't actually a stated requirement.  This solution uses out-of-the-box-thinking™ that is a hallmark of greatness.  I would like to see it with two columns in the output, so the output could be more easily confirmed as correct.

Answer (score 14):

Using a SQL Server 2014 memory optimized table and a natively compiled procedure:

```
-- Setup
CREATE DATABASE InMem;
GO
ALTER DATABASE InMem
ADD FILEGROUP FG1
CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
GO
ALTER DATABASE InMem
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = 'FN1', 
    -- Change to suit your system
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQL2014\MSSQL\DATA\FN1.mod'
)
TO FILEGROUP FG1;
GO
USE InMem;
GO
CREATE TYPE dbo.FizzBuzzTableType AS TABLE 
(
    n integer NOT NULL INDEX i,
    FizzBuzz varchar(8) NOT NULL
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);
GO
```

Native procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.FizzBuzz
WITH 
    NATIVE_COMPILATION, 
    SCHEMABINDING, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN ATOMIC 
WITH 
(
    TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, 
    LANGUAGE = N'english'
)   
    DECLARE @n AS dbo.FizzBuzzTableType;

    DECLARE @i integer = 1;
    WHILE @i < 50
    BEGIN
        IF @i % 15 = 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT @n (n, FizzBuzz) 
            VALUES (@i, 'FizzBuzz')
        END
        ELSE 
        BEGIN
            IF @i % 3 = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT @n (n, FizzBuzz)
                VALUES (@i, 'Fizz')
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                IF @i % 5 = 0
                BEGIN
                    INSERT @n (n, FizzBuzz) 
                    VALUES (@i, 'Buzz')
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    INSERT @n (n, FizzBuzz) 
                    VALUES (@i, CONVERT(varchar(8), @i));
                END;
            END;
        END;

        SET @i += 1;
    END;

    SELECT
        N.n, 
        N.FizzBuzz
    FROM @n AS N
    ORDER BY
        N.n;
END;
```

Test:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
GO
DECLARE @T AS dbo.FizzBuzzTableType;

INSERT @T (n, FizzBuzz)
EXECUTE dbo.FizzBuzz;
GO 100

PRINT SYSUTCDATETIME();
```

Typical results:

```
-- 95ms for 100 iterations, < 1ms each
2014-12-31 10:07:13.7993355
Beginning execution loop
Batch execution completed 100 times.
2014-12-31 10:07:13.8943409
```

This writes the procedure output to an in-memory table variable, because otherwise we're just testing the speed of displaying results in SSMS.

#### One million rows

The above native procedure takes about **12 seconds** to run on 1,000,000 numbers. There are all sorts of faster ways to do the same thing in T-SQL. One I have written before follows. It runs in about **500ms** on my laptop on a million rows when the intended parallel plan is achieved:

```
IF  OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Result', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Result;

IF  OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Thousand', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Thousand;

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @start datetime2(7) = SYSUTCDATETIME();

CREATE TABLE #Thousand 
(
    n integer NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_#Thousand
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (n)
);

-- Add 1,000 rows numbered 0-999 to #Thousand
WITH 
    L1 (n) AS
(
    SELECT  V.n
    FROM    
    (
        VALUES  (0), (1), (2), (3), (4),
                (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)
    ) AS V (n)
),
    Thousand AS
(
    SELECT  n = 
        CONVERT
        (
            integer,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
            - 1
        )
    FROM L1
    CROSS JOIN L1 AS L2
    CROSS JOIN L1 AS L3
)
INSERT #Thousand (n)
SELECT n
FROM Thousand;

-- To hold the Fizz Buzz output
CREATE TABLE #Result 
(
    n integer NOT NULL, 
    result varchar(8) NOT NULL
);

INSERT #Result
SELECT 
    Million.n, 
    Million.result
FROM
(
    -- Modulo operation to encourage few outer rows parallelism
    SELECT  n
    FROM    #Thousand
    WHERE   n % 1 = 0
) AS T1
-- Outer Apply to keep the Compute Scalar parallel
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT
        F2.n, 
        F2.result
    FROM #Thousand AS T2
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- Row numbers 1 to 1,000,000
        SELECT  (T1.n * 1000) + T2.n + 1
    ) AS F1 (n)
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        -- The Fizz Buzz bit
        SELECT
            F1.n,
            result =
                CASE 
                    WHEN F1.n % 15 = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz'
                    WHEN F1.n % 3 = 0 THEN 'Buzz'
                    WHEN F1.n % 5 = 0 THEN 'Fizz'
                    ELSE CONVERT(varchar(8), F1.n)
                END
    ) AS F2
) AS Million
OPTION  (MAXDOP 4, QUERYTRACEON 9481);

PRINT DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, @start, SYSUTCDATETIME());
```

Comment: You said "Outer Apply to keep the Compute Scalar parallel" - can you point me at something about that?

Comment: Nope. It just so happens outer apply can help prevent compute scalars moving out of the parallel zone sometimes. Completely undocumented, could change any day etc.

Answer (score 10):

This one runs the same on my machine as your first one (0ms). I'm not sure if it would scale faster or not.

```
;WITH t AS (
    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o.object_id)
    FROM sys.objects o
)
SELECT t.RowNum
    , Cxa.Fizz + CxB.Buzz
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t.RowNum % 3 = 0 THEN 'FIZZ' ELSE '' END) CxA(Fizz)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t.RowNum % 5 = 0 THEN 'BUZZ' ELSE '' END) CxB(Buzz)
WHERE t.RowNum < 50;
```

Answer (score 9):

The best version I came up with runs in 30ms on my machine:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 1 As RowNum
    Union ALL
    Select RowNum + 1
    From t
    Where RowNum < 49
)
SELECT t.RowNum
, SubString('FIZZ', (t.RowNum % 3)*10, 5) + SubString('BUZZ', (t.RowNum % 5)*10, 5)
FROM t;
```

Answer (score 5):

According to sqlfiddle.com this takes 7 ms:

```
select coalesce(fizz + buzz, fizz, buzz, cast(n as varchar)) as FizzBuzz
  from (
    select n0 + 3 * n3 + 9 * n9 + 27 * n27 + 81 * n81 as n
        from
            (select 0 as n0  union all select 1 union all select 2 as n0)  as n0,
            (select 0 as n3  union all select 1 union all select 2 as n3)  as n3,
            (select 0 as n9  union all select 1 union all select 2 as n9)  as n9,
            (select 0 as n27 union all select 1 union all select 2 as n27) as n27,
            (select 0 as n81 union all select 1                    as n81) as n81
  ) as stupidalias1
  left outer join
    (select 3 as fizzstep, 'Fizz' as fizz) as stupidalias2 on n % fizzstep = 0
  left outer join
    (select 5 as buzzstep, 'Buzz' as buzz) as stupidalias3 on n % buzzstep = 0
  where n between 1 and 100
  order by n;
```

Doesn't use any tables, stored procs, or CTEs.

Answer (score 5):

I got a reasonable version of the natively compiled stored proc working for 1 million rows in ~500-800ms.  This is a T-SQL conversion I did of the bitwise algorithim from [here](http://www.zoharbabin.com/which-fizzbuzz-solution-is-the-most-efficient/) with a little help from Adam Machanic's blog on bitwise operations [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/bitmask-handling-part-4-left-shift-and-right-shift.aspx).

I'm (hopefully) following the same rules as @PaulWhite's 500ms / 1 million row proc, ie generating the results but not displaying them / not passing them around as part of the timing.  It has to be hash indexes on the in-memory tables for speed and bucket sizes of 4,194,304 or 8,388,608 seemed to be the sweet spot for me, although obviously that gives high empty bucket counts.

```
USE hekatondb
GO

--NB: SQLCMD script, Enable via: Query menu > SQLCMD Mode
:setvar bucketCount 4194304
--:setvar bucketCount 8388608

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_hekatonFizzBuzz') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROC dbo.usp_hekatonFizzBuzz 
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FizzBuzz') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.FizzBuzz
GO


IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.FizzBuzz') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE dbo.FizzBuzz (
    Number      INT NOT NULL,
    Result      VARCHAR(8) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_FizzBuzz PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH ( Number ) WITH ( BUCKET_COUNT = $(bucketCount) )

) WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON, DURABILITY = SCHEMA_ONLY )
GO


CREATE PROC dbo.usp_hekatonFizzBuzz 

    @limit  INT

WITH
    NATIVE_COMPILATION, 
    SCHEMABINDING, 
    EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN ATOMIC
WITH
(
    TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL = SNAPSHOT, 
    LANGUAGE = N'english'
)   

    DECLARE @acc INT = 810092048    -- 11 00 00 01 00 10 01 00 00 01 10 00 01 00 00
    DECLARE @i INT = 1
    DECLARE @c INT

    WHILE @i <= @limit
    BEGIN 

        SELECT
            @c = @acc & 3,
            @acc = ( @acc / 4 ) | ( @c * 268435456 )

        INSERT dbo.FizzBuzz ( Number, Result )
        SELECT @i, SUBSTRING( '       Fizz    Buzz    FizzBuzz', @c * 8, @c * 4 )

        SET @i += 1

    END

END
GO

DELETE dbo.FizzBuzz
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME2 = SYSUTCDATETIME();

EXEC dbo.usp_hekatonFizzBuzz 1000000

SELECT DATEDIFF( millisecond, @startDate, SYSUTCDATETIME() ) diff
GO 10
```

Answer (score 4):

I found and played with this single sub select with no CTE. max_elapsed_time in query stats shows 1036

```
 SELECT num,
        CASE    WHEN mod3 + mod5 = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz'
                WHEN mod5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz'
                WHEN mod3 = 0 THEN 'Fizz'
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), num)
        END
 FROM 
 (
    SELECT  number as num,
            number % 3 AS mod3,
            number % 5 AS mod5
    FROM    master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE   name IS NULL
            AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 101
 ) AS numbers;
```

Answer (score 4):

I take no credit for the code as written, I just wanted to see how long it would take on

ONE BILLION ROWS!

```
;WITH T(N) AS (SELECT N FROM (VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) AS X(N))
    ,NUMS(N) AS (SELECT TOP(1000000000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))  AS N FROM T T1,T T2,T T3,T T4,T T5,T T6,T T7,T T8,T T9, T T10)
    SELECT  n, ca.fb
    INTO #fizzywizzy
    FROM    NUMS n
            CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    CASE WHEN n.N % 15 = 0 THEN 'FizzBuzz'
                                         WHEN n.N % 3 = 0 THEN 'Fizz'
                                         WHEN n.N % 5 = 0 THEN 'Buzz'
                                         ELSE CAST(n AS VARCHAR)
                                    END AS [fb]
                        ) ca
```

The answer is: about 10 minutes.

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 13 ms, elapsed time = 13 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 648625 ms,  elapsed time = 618025 ms.
```

Answer (score -1):

## PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL provides [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html), a Table-Value Function (Set-Returning Function) which makes this substantially simpler. I'm assuming you don't want anything output whatsoever when the number neither 3, nor 5 goes into it.

```
SELECT x, str
FROM generate_series(1,49) AS gs(x)
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (VALUES (CASE
  WHEN x % 15 =0 THEN 'Fizzbuzz'
  WHEN x % 3  =0 THEN 'Fizz'
  WHEN x % 5  =0 THEN 'Buzz'
END)) AS c(str)
WHERE str IS NOT NULL;
```